# CSS Column Height not Inheriting

Tags: css, height, doctype, inheritance

I'm trying to get this... http://jsfiddle.net/K2NPz/1/

Turned into... http://postimage.org/image/1zjcktz2c/

The left picture is current, the right is ideal. I can't seem to get it working though since the inherit property (and the 100%) aren't actually doing anything. It *DOES* work in Quirks mode, but I need it working with an actual realistic Doctype (HTML5 or XHTML 1.0 Strict).

Comment: First off, I would pull out all the inline styles and put them into a style sheet.  It would be a lot easier to debug that way.

Comment: I'm doing an html newsletter maker, so that's not as possible as one might think.

Comment: Is this newsletter going to be emailed?

Comment: Yes =P. At least that's the intention.

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%` means 100% of the parent element, but the `renderzone` div has no height specified. According to [the W3C's specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property), when "height:100%" ...

> If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

The logic surrounding "auto" is considerably complex, so I can't give you an answer for how to work with that, but I am able to get something similar to what you want by setting all of the parent containers (including "body" & "html") to `height:100%` as suggested by [this document](http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/). It will need tweaking, but should set you in the right direction.

Comment: With height:100%: http://jsfiddle.net/aQkxD/
The text gets wider when it passes the green background, but that can be fixed with the `overflow-y` property: http://jsfiddle.net/LucNk/1/